# How can i insert data in another table while using outer apply in the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 
    C.NCLAIMID, C.SATTYFILENO, C.DTLASTPMT,
    C.CURLASTPMTAMT AS LASTPMTAMT, L.ACTUALPMTDATE, L.ACTUALLASTPMTAMT,
    C.SWORKSTATIONID, C.DTCHANGEDON, C.NCHANGEDBY, C.NAPPLICATIONID
INTO 
     CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2 (NCLAIMID, SATTYFILENO, DTLASTPMT, LASTPMTAMT, ACTUALPMTDATE, ACTUALLASTPMTAMT, SWORKSTATIONID, DTCHANGEDON, NCHANGEDBY, NAPPLICATIONID)
FROM 
    CLAIM AS C WITH(NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         NCLAIMID, DTTRANSACTION AS ACTUALPMTDATE, CURTRANAMT AS ACTUALLASTPMTAMT 
     FROM 
         CLAIMREGISTRY WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE 
         NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID 
         AND NTRANLINKID IS NULL
         AND NTRANSACTIONCODEID IN (1, 13)
     ORDER BY 
         DTTRANSACTION DESC) AS L 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, C.DTLASTPMT, 112) <> CONVERT(VARCHAR, L.ACTUALPMTDATE, 112)
```

Comment: Be careful slapping that NOLOCK hint all over the place. It has a lot of baggage that most people don't realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2` exists:

```
insert into CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2(
    NCLAIMID
  , SATTYFILENO
  , DTLASTPMT
  , LASTPMTAMT
  , ACTUALPMTDATE
  , ACTUALLASTPMTAMT
  , SWORKSTATIONID
  , DTCHANGEDON
  , NCHANGEDBY
  , NAPPLICATIONID
)
select 
    C.NCLAIMID
  , C.SATTYFILENO
  , C.DTLASTPMT
  , C.CURLASTPMTAMT as LASTPMTAMT
  , L.ACTUALPMTDATE
  , L.ACTUALLASTPMTAMT
  , C.SWORKSTATIONID
  , C.DTCHANGEDON
  , C.NCHANGEDBY
  , C.NAPPLICATIONID
from CLAIM as C with (nolock)
outer apply (
  select top 1 NCLAIMID
    , DTTRANSACTION as ACTUALPMTDATE
    , CURTRANAMT as ACTUALLASTPMTAMT
  from CLAIMREGISTRY with (nolock)
  where NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID 
    and NTRANLINKID is null 
    and NTRANSACTIONCODEID in (1, 13)
  order by DTTRANSACTION desc
 ) as L
where CONVERT(date, C.DTLASTPMT) <> CONVERT(date, L.ACTUALPMTDATE)
```

---

if `CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2` does not exist:

```
 select 
    C.NCLAIMID
  , C.SATTYFILENO
  , C.DTLASTPMT
  , C.CURLASTPMTAMT as LASTPMTAMT
  , L.ACTUALPMTDATE
  , L.ACTUALLASTPMTAMT
  , C.SWORKSTATIONID
  , C.DTCHANGEDON
  , C.NCHANGEDBY
  , C.NAPPLICATIONID
into CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2
from CLAIM as C with (nolock)
outer apply (
  select top 1 NCLAIMID
    , DTTRANSACTION as ACTUALPMTDATE
    , CURTRANAMT as ACTUALLASTPMTAMT
  from CLAIMREGISTRY with (nolock)
  where NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID 
    and NTRANLINKID is null 
    and NTRANSACTIONCODEID in (1, 13)
  order by DTTRANSACTION desc
 ) as L
where CONVERT(date, C.DTLASTPMT) <> CONVERT(date, L.ACTUALPMTDATE)
```